# expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined in React but no import

Tags: reactjs

I have this project in React and I am trying to import a function from another place, a file .js, but there is a problem:

[image]

this is my function:

```
import { DragIconWrapper } from "../styles";
import { ReactComponent as DragHandleIcon } from "../drag_handle-black-18dp.svg";
import React from "react";

function DragHandle(props) {
  return (
    <DragIconWrapper {...props}>
      <DragHandleIcon />
    </DragIconWrapper>
  )
}

export default DragHandle;
```

I import the function in my class in another file .jsx like this:

```
import  DragHandle  from "./partials/DragHandle";
```

and using like this:

```
                <ListContainer>
                {this.props.questions.map((question, index) => {
                    return (
                        question.operacionId === 1 ?
                        <ListItem> 
                            <DragHandle/>
```

what could I have been doing wrong. When I use it in another project like this, works:

```
  <ListContainer>
    <h1>The List</h1>
    {list.map((item, i) => (
      <ListItem>
        <DragHandle />
        <span>{item.title}</span>
      </ListItem>
    ))}
  </ListContainer>
```

Comment: is `./partials/DragHandle` the correct directory structure? Should it be `../partials/Draghandle` or something else like that instead?

Comment: @RobinClower, yes it is, there is a folder called Questions, inside there is only 1 folder called partials with a file called DragHandle.js, everything else including the file Questions.jsx is outside.